# Conditional sorting of an array (Ruby)

Tags: arrays, ruby, sorting

I want to sort an array alphabetically, unless two words have the same first letter, in which case the returned array should show them in the order they appeared in the given string.

E.g. "I really love lamas" => ["I", "love", "lamas", "really"]

I've written the following but just get error messages. Can I tweak this so it works, or am I totally going down the wrong path?

```
"I really love lamas".split.sort.collect do |a, z|
  if a[0] == z[0]
  puts a z
  else 
  z a
  end
```

Comment: You mean 2 consecutive words? Or words from any distance? Note. `#collect` gives only item per iteration, so it will be `do |a|`, not `do |a, z|`

Comment: "I've written the following but just get error messages." – And what do they say? What line do they occur on? Often, error messages contain some advice. Did you follow it?

Comment: To put some flesh on @JörgWMittag's comment, your error message would have been `NoMethodError (undefined method '[]' for nil:NilClass)` in the line `if a[0] == z[0]`. The receiver of the method `[]` is `a` on the left of `==` and `b` on the right. That tells us that `a` is `nil` or `b` is `nil` (or both), as `nil` has no method `[]`. If you rerun your code with the statement  `puts "a=#{a}, z=#{z}"` you will find that `a #=> "I"` (the first word) and `z #=> nil`. `z` is `nil` because a single string (`"I") is being passed to the block, so you should only have one block variable...

Comment: ...Ruby computes `a,z = "I"`, which assigns `"I"` to `a` and `nil` to `z`. As you see the (first) error is pinpointed by the error message. Error message deserve careful study.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

A block need to be specified to [Array#sort](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-sort) method.

The block must implement a comparison between a and b, and return -1, when a follows b, 0 when a and b are equivalent, or +1 if b follows a.

So the logic is: return `0` if first letters the same; otherwise compare the whole string using `<=>`. After the sorting, join the elements to a single string

```
"I really love lamas".split.sort do |a, z|
  if a[0] == z[0]
    0
  else
    a <=> z
  end
end.join(" ")
```

Comment: `sort` isn't stable

Comment: Further to @matthewd's comment, this only works when the `sort` algorithm employed has the property that, for every pair of elements `a` and `b` in `arr`, when `a <=> b #=> 0`, `a` will precede `b` in the sorted array if and and only if `a` precedes `b` in `arr`. Here is a simple example of a sort method that does not have that property: `class Array; def my_sort; reverse.sort; end; end; "I really love llamas".split.my_sort do |a,z| a[0] == z[0] ? 0 : a <=> z; end.join(" ") #=> "I llamas love really"`,

Answer (score 3):

```
str = "I really love llamas"   

str.split.each_with_index.
          sort { |(a,i),(b,j)| a[0]==b[0] ? i<=>j : a<=>b }.
          map(&:first)
  #=> ["I", "love", "llamas", "really"]
```

The steps are as follows.

```
a = str.split
  #=> ["I", "really", "love", "llamas"]
b = a.each_with_index
  #=> #<Enumerator: ["I", "really", "love", "llamas"]:each_with_index>
```

We can convert this enumerator to an array to see the values it will generate and pass to the block, to be assigned as values to the block variables `a` and `z`.

```
b.to_a
  #=> [["I", 0], ["really", 1], ["love", 2], ["llamas", 3]]
```

Continuing,

```
c = b.sort { |(a,i),(b,j)| a[0]==b[0] ? i<=>j : a<=>b }
  #=> [["I", 0], ["love", 2], ["llamas", 3], ["really", 1]]
c.map(&:first)
  #=> ["I", "love", "llamas", "really"]
```